# ENTITY FRAMEWORK CORE 5 - Return two oracle cursors from single stored procedure

Tags: oracle, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-5

I'm working on an API that calls an oracle stored procedure -I can't touch it- and returns **two** refcursors. The problem is that in my code, only the first cursor beign returned from the sp gets mapped, while the other one trows an *InvalidOperationException*.

### My repository class

```
var sql = "BEGIN CCO_PKG_WHITDRAWREQUEST.OBT_OPCION_RET_DES_PRC(:pi_num_seguro_social , :pi_num_resolucion, :po_cur_valida_res, :po_cur_opciones); END;";

            var parameters = new OracleParameter[]
            {
                new OracleParameter("pi_num_seguro_social", request.NSS),
                new OracleParameter("pi_num_resolucion", request.NumResolucion),
                new OracleParameter("po_cur_valida_res", OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.Output),
                new OracleParameter("po_cur_opciones", OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.Output)
            };
            
            //This one gets mapped without problems.
            var validaResCursor = await _context.CursorValidaRes.FromSqlRaw(sql, parameters).ToListAsync();
            
            //This one throws the exception.
            var opcionesCursor = await _context.CursorOpciones.FromSqlRaw(sql, parameters).ToListAsync();

            var result = (opcionesCursor, validaResCursor);
```

### The cursor's class that gets mapped

```
    [Keyless]
    public class ValidaResCursor
    {
        public string EsCVEValido { get; set; }
        public string Opcion { get; set; }
        public string Descripcion { get; set; }
        public double SaldoA { get; set; }
        public double SaldoB { get; set; }
        public string Vigencia { get; set; }
    }
}
```

### The cursor's class that doesn't

```
    [Keyless]
    public class OpcionesCursor
    {
        public string cv { get; set; }
        public string tipo { get; set; }
        public string descripcion { get; set; }
        public double monto { get; set; }
        public double salario_bc { get; set; }
    }
```

### Execution

[The first cursor gets mapped correctly (It only has 1 row).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42g9b.png)

### Error

[The second cursor throws an error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XXtj.png)

This is the first time I'm working with oracle in a dotnet enviroment, but I'm following the oficial guide from oracle, (see. https://github.com/oracle/dotnet-db-samples/blob/master/samples/dotnet-core/ef-core/stored-procedure/return-ref-cursor.cs) and as you can see, aparently it only works with sp's that returns only one cursor. Any ideas? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Currently this is not supported by EF Core: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/8127 take a look at the link to find alternatives to this problem.

Comment: You're right, now I'm using dapper instead of EF exclusively for these multiple-cursors procedures.